# How to copy a database using Azure ARM API's ?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-database-mysql

There is an api to create or update a database.

PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/databases/{databaseName}?api-version=2014-04-0

How can I create a **copy of a existing database**?

Should I have to do GET on existing database to get the properties and then create a copy database using the properties? Will it create exactcopy of database ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [rest api reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate) you should use the same call you are using, but in the body you must pass in `createMode = copy` and `sourceDatabaseId = ID`.

```
{
    "subscriptionId": "00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444",
    "resourceGroupName": "sqlcrudtest-4799",
    "serverName": "sqlcrudtest-6440",
    "databaseName": "testdb",
    "api-version": "2014-04-01",
    "parameters": {
        "location": "Japan East",
        "properties": {
            "createMode": "Copy",
            "sourceDatabaseId": "/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/sqlcrudtest-4799/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlcrudtest-3782/databases/testdb"
        }
    }
},
```

ps. scroll down (on the page I've linked) until you find an example called `Create a database as a copy`

Comment: Awesome !! Working like a start .. Thanks :-)

Comment: It just return 202 response -  it means "in progress".How i need to ensure that process was completed.

Comment: you should create a separate question for that